# How to force std::vector type for fixed-length arrays in msg?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

According to this page http://wiki.ros.org/msg fixed-length arrays in msg files can be interpreted as `boost::array` or `std::vector`.

Whenever I tried to apply any vector logic to a message with a fixed-length array (let's say `uint8[8]`) it would throw errors saying that the type is of `boost::array`.

How can I enforce `std::vector` type on fixed-sized fields inside ROS messages?

EDIT: here's an example: http://docs.ros.org/api/can_msgs/html/msg/Frame.html, I would like to have data field as `std::vector` without changing the field itself to `uint8[]`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313180/how-to-force-std::vector-type-for-fixed-length-arrays-in-msg?/) by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2019-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation is not saying you can use either type, it is saying that depending on the version it will either be a `boost::array` or a `std::vector`. In your case the type is `boost::array` so you will need to access it using that object type.

You would need to copy the data into a std::vector if you wanted to use that functionality since `boost::array` is a fixed length data type so cannot support the features of `std::vector`.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2019-01-19**:
Thank you. One quick question, for that message format I would have to copy data from callback rather than pointing it with a pointer, right?

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2019-01-19**:
Also, do you have any references where I could look at how to properly copy boost::arrays? I am not familiar with boost at all unfortunately.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-01-19**:
The [reference is here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost/array.html), it has size() method identical to `std::vector` and uses [square brackets] for element access. That should cover most tasks.

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2019-01-19**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd, really appreciated, that looks exactly what I need!